# Metric for calculating lopsided distributions

Tags: distributions, descriptive-statistics, skewness

I have a list of ~20 numbers:

> 1200, 1200, 360, 360, 300, 250, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 90, 90, 90, 90, 45, 10, 0, 0

I am looking for a metric that determines the *lopsidedness* (maybe skewness) of this distribution. For the above example, I would want to be able to highlight that the sum of the first 2 numbers (2400) make up nearly 50% of the total sum (4985). But there could also be other examples where the top 4 or 5 numbers make up a big percentage (say, greater than 50%) of the total sum.

Should I just calculate *skewness* or are there other better metrics that fulfill my requirement, e.g. standard deviation?